# 16-port 19" rackmount PoE Switch with low noise

Tags: networking, switch, poe, fanless

I'm looking for a switch with at least 12-16 ports, Gigabit that supports Power over Ethernet on at least 4 of it's ports that can be rack-mounted (19") and it ideally is fanless or has very low noise.

What I found so far is the "Cisco Catalyst C2960L-16PS-LL" but it is rather expensive, also in my area I have either wait 4 weeks on it or pay 150 USD more to get it in two days. Pro: it is fanless.

Then I also found the Unifi 16‑150W - it has 1 fan but most people tell that the fans never go on even with 4-6 PoE devices attached. Only in rare occasions the fans turn on to cool the unit down a bit.

Any recommendations?

Comment: What's your budget? How low noise is low noise? Does it need to be a managed switch, or is unmanaged fine? My first thought is to get a Nortel 5520 or something of the like and switch the fans out for Noctua ones, but that may be massively overkill for your needs.

Comment: Yes, managed is a must, budget is 300-400 USD. Low noise for me is like a very silent refrigerator from 1 meter distance, hard to explain of course.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one else answered I will give the answer, as in the meantime I choose the "Ubiquiti Unifi 16-150W" switch. It has one (maybe even 2) fans, but they only come on at a certain temperature and at startup. I have never heard them running after startup in my case, but I only have 2 PoE devices.